# Sharing variable between .exe and .dll

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dll

I'm creating application that loads external dlls using LoadLibrary(). Then I load functions and variables by GetProcAddress(). Functions are called, variables loaded.

But I want to make that, for example i have got int which is 5 in DLL, I load it in .exe and in that .exe I set it to 10. But when I cout that int in DLL it says 5 and in .exe it prints 10. So that means that variables aren't shared and i'm just loading values.

Does anybody know how can i do that?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include a [mre], enough code that we can compile to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I already found out. The problem was that I used ++ operator. When i used +=, -=, = it worked fine so the problem is solved.

Comment: I'm 100% positive that the  (*++*) operator is not it. Please update the question with the code you used.